# What's with Luke's arm?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

At the end of the Last Jedi, Luke

> disappears. Luke, of course, lost his arm at the end of Empire...and in the previous two examples of this particularly tidy death tradition, it's clear that only the body, and not the clothes, for example, disappear. His mechanical arm didn't clatter to the stone beneath, as one would expect.

Is this simply an oversight?

Comment: What if ~~cue spooky music~~ Luke was a ghost the whole time?

Comment: Actually, it seems death via Force ghosting is rather particular about which clothes and accessories also become one with the Force. Obi-Wan left behind a cloak/robe but not the rest of his outfit. Yoda went in his... pajamas, but left the bedsheet. It was only Luke’s cloak that drifted away, too. Perhaps he thought, “well, if I’m going to be haunting Rey and Ben as a blue ghost later, I don’t want to do it naked and missing a hand, so I’d better bring these with me.”

Comment: That would mean that somewhere halfway across the galaxy a skeletal hand evaporated. The oversight is yours; I'd expect neither of those outcomes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It has already been established that when a Jedi becomes one with the Force, that they (sometimes) take physical objects with them. Yoda goes with his robes and his necklace.

Kenobi, by comparison, seems to have left his robe as a distraction to Vader so it's certainly possible that a Jedi can *choose* what to take with them. Presumably Luke wanted to take his creepy robot hand for sentimental reasons.

---

It may amuse you to learn that the writers [actually gave this question serious consideration](https://media.giphy.com/media/XsUtdIeJ0MWMo/source.gif).

> **[Q](https://twitter.com/JustinOArnold/status/954404628392763392?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fscreenrant.com%2Fstar-wars-luke-robotic-hand-force%2F)**: *So Luke has a metal hand and passes into the Force. Does the hand go with him when he goes? Does he get a new hand? WHAT HAPPENS?*
>
> [**Mark Hamill**](https://twitter.com/HamillHimself): *Me too. Let me know if you get an answer.*
>
> **[Rian Johnson](https://twitter.com/rianjohnson):** *In the edit room someone joke suggested that when he fades away his robot hand should clank down onto the rock.
> Might have undercut the moment.*
>
> [**Danny Zuker**](https://twitter.com/DannyZuker): *This was a significant debate in our writers’ room.
> I was in the anti-clank camp.*
>
> <sub><sup>[via twitter](https://twitter.com/JustinOArnold/status/954404628392763392?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fscreenrant.com%2Fstar-wars-luke-robotic-hand-force%2F)</sup></sub>

Comment: But when we saw Obi-Wan later on as a ghost he wasn't naked, so force ghosts can at least somewhat alter their appearances. Or Obi-Wan was wearing two sets of robes when he fought Vader on the Death Star.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs - Well, we know that Jedi can appear differently than they did at death; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/5/55/JediGhosts-ROTJ.png/revision/latest?cb=20130420050659

Comment: I had misremembered Yoda's death as leaving his robes behind...I guess I was confusing his blanket with his robes...

Comment: @Valorum nonsense, that never happened. I refuse to acknowledge that.

Comment: Or maybe there was some other set of robes, at home in Obiwan's wardrobe, that vanished at the exact same time he did.

Comment: @kaine - This (non-canon) version also looks different from how Anakin ever looked; https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhf3j.jpg

Comment: Whats is the limit? Can some one bring a death star as sentimental reasons? Is this limited to not living things? Can one take his sister instead of his robes?

Comment: I thought someone did take the death star with them. It certainly doesn't seem to be there any more ...

Comment: That and the film makers have already admitted it was a mistake.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that there's a degree of contiguity required. Maybe it's part of the Jedi's conception of body and self that drives it.

Comment: Aren't force ghosts supposed to appear to just one  selected person? May be they appear in a form that person wants to see them in hence Luke sees him as Anakin ( light side, the way he wants to see him ) instead of darth vader. Hence the needs for obiwan's robe as well. Luke doesn't want to see him naked

Comment: @user13267 - Qui-Gon made appearances to Obi-Wan and (separately) Yoda. Obi-Wan made separate appearances to Yoda and Luke within the space of a few minutes.